# %in% vs '==' when comparing date with date_as_string

Tags: r

I'm confused why `%in%` and `'=='` give different results here:

```
day_string <- '2017-07-20'
day_date <- as.Date(day_string)

day_string == day_date #TRUE
day_string %in% day_date #FALSE
```

From `%in%` help:
`%in%` is currently defined as `"%in%" <- function(x, table) match(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0`

So if I understand things correctly, since `match` coerces date to character (but first to numeric),

```
day_string %in% day_date
```

is translated to

```
match(day_string, as.character(as.numeric(day_date)), nomatch = 0) > 0
```

However `'=='` help says it also coerces different types. What does `'=='` actually do in the example above and why it behaves differently than `%in%`?

Comment: `"=="` has methods -- in this case `?Ops.Date` is triggered. On the other hand `match`, at least until now, ignores the "Date" class (in contrast to "POSIXlt" class -- `day_string %in% as.POSIXlt(day_date)`) and all it "sees" is a "character" and a "double" that are coerced accordingly.

Comment: @alexis_laz would you mind posting the reason that you very well explained as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relational operator `"=="` is (as noted in `?"=="`) a generic function that has/can have methods defined either directly (`"==.class"`) or through the `Ops` generic group (`Ops.class`). Such functions is highly probable that have methods to account for R's base classes like the "Date" class and could work as expected, as is the case with `"=="` through `?Ops.Date`. We can see if the "Date" class is supported by a generic function by `methods(class = "Date")`.

On the other hand, `match` (and its wrapper `"%in%"`) is not generic and could not necessarily be expected to account for the "class" attribute of its arguments (even for R's own classes). In cases of classes where it does account for is because it was explicitly designed to account for a specific class and such a fact *may* be documented in the respective help page. This is the case ([has not always been](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/POSIXlt-matching-bug-td2272307.html)), for example, with the "POSIXlt" class (`day_string %in% as.POSIXlt(day_date)` works as desired). So, `"%in%"` ignores the class of "day_date" and all it sees is that it's been passed a `typeof(day_date)` (`unclass(day_date)`) and a `typeof(day_string)` where appropriate coercions are made (say, something like `as.character.default(day_date)`) according to `?match`.

Answer (score 3):

From the help of `?==` "*If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is coerced to the type of the other*" 
So I guess while `==` has two same type vectors to compare, `%in%` is trying to compare a date with a character.

However, this only happens with date Vs character, i.e.

```
as.character(5) %in% 5
#[1] TRUE

as.factor('abc') %in% 'abc'
#[1] TRUE

5 %in% 5L
#[1] TRUE
```

In the case of the OP, as @Cath mentions, `df_date` is first converted to numeric and then to character so the final comparing is,

```
as.character(as.numeric(day_date))
#[1] "17367"

as.character(as.numeric(day_date)) %in% day_string
#[1] FALSE
```

Double Checking,

```
'17367' %in% as.Date(day_string)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: for `%in%` it is also converted to `character` but first to numeric, as stated in the Q so `day_date` is actually converted to `"17367"`

Comment: Yes. '17367' %in% as.Date(day_string) # TRUE

Comment: I still don't understand what '==' does. Does '==' coerce the date straight to a character without the as.numeric intermezzo? If so, why '==' behaves this way and match does not?